# oracle monitoring db status via php

Tags: sql, oracle, monitoring

I am looking for a way to monitor Oracle Database status (health) via PHP script. There are system variables containing actual number of connection, sessions, work load, etc...

How I can access to those values: via regular SELECT statement, or build-in store procedure, or it need to be custom build store procedure...

How I can detect, after I get those values, is it a mormal, heavy, extreme work load. What are criterias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - talk about an open-ended question! I'm afraid that typing in a memory dump of everything every DBA has learned about monitoring databases is kinda outside the scope of a single response. Yes, there are lots of system variables. Yes they all have meaning (often in relation to other system variables). And yes, you will need to learn them to figure out what is a heavy workload for a particular database instance depending on that instance's configuration and the specs of the underlying system.

A good starting place might be for you to look at ORAMON: http://oramon.dbapool.com/index.php

From there, you can spend time researching various other database health statistics, how to get them and what they mean, and then add them into the ORAMON framework or build your own.